# ImageMagick: multiple files conversion & saving with different name

Tags: shell, filenames, wildcards, imagemagick

I am creating a bash script. How can I perform a set of operations/transformations (of choice) on all `.jpg` images in a different directory using `ImageMagick`'s `convert` utility ? The converted image should be named `*-change.jpg`

Here's my code:

```
convert $file/*.jpg -flip $file/*-change.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the output file name via [`-set`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#set) + some [percent escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) (in this case you need the directory component of the path `%d` and the file name without extension `%t`):

```
convert "${dir}"/*.jpg -flip -set filename:t '%d/%t-change' '%[filename:t].jpg'
```

---

<sup>I used `t` as a `filename:`property  but really, you can use whatever you want...</sup>

Comment: that was quick answer. thanks can you please explain what is %d/%t

Comment: @maria - I've edited the post but if you follow the link in my answer you'll find the description for all percent escapes...